# convert CSS background-image property in to LESS css

Tags: css, less

How to convert the following CSS3 in to LESS Mixin. can any one help on this.

```
.progress-striped {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

Comment: What exactly you wanna do?

Comment: i have background-image property in multiple places. so i want to convert in to LESS mixin

Comment: The `webkit-gradient` in your question seems different from the rest as it doesn't seem to have an angle. Anyway, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243226/create-four-color-gradient-mixin-in-bootstrap). Bass Jobsen's answer has a way of creating your own mixins (a bit lower down in the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wanna use something like this?

```
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops...) {
  background: nth(nth($color-stops, 1), 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction($direction), $color-stops);
  background: linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
}
```

Refer [Building a Linear-gradient Mixin in Sass](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-linear-gradient-mixin-sass/) for more info. Sass and LESS are almost the same in mixins.

The full mixin is:

```
/// Mixin printing a linear-gradient
/// as well as a plain color fallback
/// and the `-webkit-` prefixed declaration
/// @access public
/// @param {Keyword | Angle} $direction - Linear gradient direction
/// @param {Arglist} $color-stops - List of color-stops composing the gradient
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops...) {
  background: nth(nth($color-stops, 1), 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction($direction), $color-stops);
  background: linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
}
```

And the usage is:

```
@include linear-gradient(hotpink, tomato);
```